# Grails: change the default folder a controller uses for gsp discovery

Tags: grails, spring-mvc

Is there a way to configure the starting folder that a controller uses for finding it's GSP files?

I have a single Grails project (v2.0.1) and I want to be able to organise my controller and views into packages that reflect my functions.

i.e. my controllers:

```
uk.co.myCompany.function1.DashboardController.groovy
uk.co.myCompany.function2.DashboardController.groovy
```

my views folder structure:

```
views -> function1 -> dashboard -> index.gsp
views -> function2 -> dashboard -> index.gsp
```

Whenever I call `render (view: 'index')` in `DashboardController`, it looks for `views/dashboard/index.gsp`.

I can change to call `render (view: '../function1/dashboard/index')` instead but this seems a bit unnecessary. Plus I obviously I have numerous other actions/pages in these controllers and don't want to enter this in every action.

A simple annotation on the controller class to specify the default folder would be ideal. Any ideas?

Comment: How would you like to access or invoke actions in `DashboardController`?

Comment: That's a core Grails convention, not sure if you can override.

Comment: If you had replied to my comment "Which controller are you talking about"? I would have replied. "Grails would have the same question: which controller you were talking about." :) . Exactly where I was going to has been mentioned by @SérgioMichels.

Comment: @dmahapatro I came up with a way to have two controllers with the same name, but they need to be in plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to organize your controllers by functionality, and they can have the same name, I suggest you to use the new [namespaces support of Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew22).

Instead of having one package for each functionality, you can create plugins, making your controller name unique by plugin.

Generating new versions of your plugins to test your app can be massive, but to avoid that you can specify your plugin location as dependency, using [grails.plugin.location](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins).

With that structure I think you can follow Grails conventions, but at the same time organize your code in functions.

---

### Example

#### Function1GrailsPlugin

- grails-app/controllers/DashboardController
- grails-app/views/dashboard/*

#### Function2GrailsPlugin

- grails-app/controllers/DashboardController
- grails-app/views/dashboard/*

#### MainApp - change `UrlMappings`

```
static mappings = {
    //requests to /function1 will be handled by the
    //DashboardController provided by the Function1 plugin
    "/function1" {
        controller = 'dashboard'
        plugin = 'function1'
    }

    //requests to /function2 will be handled by the
    //DashboardController provided by the Function2 plugin
    "/function2" {
        controller = 'dashboard'
        plugin = 'function2'
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, it would work great. But I would not create plugins only to keep my Controller Names same. From a business standpoint, the plugins will be nothing but two new artifacts in companies repository, no value add. I would rather have `Function1DashboardController` and `Function2DashboardContoller` in my app. I am not discouraging your effort but finding the value if this approach is incorporated. Do you agree?

Comment: Agreed. I see value for this only if Function1 and Function2 have a lot of controllers, then you may want to separate them in plugins for the sake of organization.

Comment: Exactly. Say for example, I came across this in here, News channel can have US content and Brazil content, you would need a dashboard, an ad-column, a sports section etc for both counties news page. The architecture is equivalent but the content would differ.